# Reduce the server's calls by spreading the calls

Tags: javascript, node.js, server, cron

I have a problem with my server every time I run my script because it's run over 500 site in about 2 minutes.
I want to spread the calls , instead of 2 minutes I want to run over 50 minutes.
I'm using Node.js and also use cron-job that runs every full hour.
The problem is that I'm using only 2 minutes of one hour instead of using the entire hour to do that (let's say every 10 minutes do something).
I'm asking to a pro way to do that.

Please help with that :-)

Comment: Some code would help.

Comment: Can you please provide this code?

Comment: If your code is callback based try using eachLimit from https://caolan.github.io/async.

If you are using promises try https://github.com/timdp/es6-promise-pool.

Both solutions allows you to limit number of concurrent calls.

Comment: But I want to make sure that I run all the sites .

Comment: So if your job runs every 10 mins instead of every hour, you need to maintain a list of the sites that you've processed already, and on the second run of the script during that hour (for example) only run the next batch of unprocessed sites (limit it to whatever number is acceptable to run concurrently). When one completes, update your list to mark it as complete for that hour, then it won't be run next time the cron executes within that hour (you could use a DB table for this, perhaps).